# Finding columns that contain both integers and NaN

Tags: matlab, matrix, nan

I have a matrix that contain Numerical values (float) and Categorical values (Int)

as

```
A = 1   NaN   2.2   3.2  4
    NaN 7.9   5.1   NaN  5
    3    5.5  NaN   4.1  NaN
```

and I'd like to split it into matrices; 
one contains the Int values and the other contains the float values as

```
 it = 1   4
      NaN 5
      3   NaN
```

and

```
  flt = NaN  2.2 3.2
      7.9  5.1 NaN
      5.5  NaN 4.1
```

i use the following code

```
int_cols = all( round(A)==A, 1 ); %// logical indexing into integer columns
it = A(:,int_cols);
flt = A(:,~int_cols);
```

However, NaN isn't equal NaN so it appears in the flt matrix and it = [].

Are there any function that can help?

Comment: Perhaps [`isnan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/isnan.html)?

Comment: What about numerical values like `5.0`? In the eyes of Matlab it's the same as `5` as long as you store them in the same double (float) array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your `all` function to the condition `isnan(A)|round(A)==A` you will get the expected output. With this condition `NaN`s are basically ignored, since having a float in any row of a column that is otherwise filled with `NaN`s will still return a false, but having `NaN`s in a column of ints will still return true. One note is that if you have a column of entirely `NaN`s it will show up as an int.

For your example:

```
A = [1   NaN   2.2   3.2  4;
     NaN 7.9   5.1   NaN  5;
     3    5.5  NaN   4.1  NaN];
int_cols = all(isnan(A)|round(A)==A,1);
it = A(:,int_cols);
flt = A(:,~int_cols);
```

After this,

```
it = 1   4
     NaN 5
     3   NaN

flt = NaN  2.2 3.2
      7.9  5.1 NaN
      5.5  NaN 4.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this,

```
A = [1   NaN   2.2   3.2  4;
     NaN 7.9   5.1   NaN  5;
     3    5.5  NaN   4.1  NaN];
B = isnan(A);
A(B) = 0;
int_cols = all( round(A)==A, 1 );
A(B) = NaN;
it = A(:,int_cols);
flt = A(:,~int_cols);
```